# save to localstorage dynamic table rows (jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, storage, local

I have dynamic table row (the table is in js).

Here is function

```
function dataToUIBio(objectDat) {
  var Table = document.getElementById("BioTbl");
  if (objectDat.length >= 0) {
    Table.innerHTML = "";
  }

  $("#intId").val(clsGlobal.parseToInteger(objectDat.intId));
  $("#nameStud").val(clsGlobal.parseToInteger(objectDat.name));
  $("#emailStud").val(clsGlobal.parseToString(objectDat.email));
  $("#ageStud").val(clsGlobal.parseToString(objData.age));
  $("#hobbyStud").val(clsGlobal.parseToInteger(objData.hobby));

  let id = "";
  let name = "";
  let email = "";
  let age = "";
  let hobby = "";

  document.getElementById("BioTbl").style.textAlign = "center";

  for (let i = 0; i < objectDat.length; i++) {
    if (objectDat[i].trStudentRecord != null) {
      id = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].trStudentRecord.intId);
      name = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].trStudentRecord.nameStud);
      email = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].trStudentRecord.emailStud);
      age = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].trStudentRecord.ageStud);
      hobby = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].trStudentRecord.hobbyStud);
    } else {
      id = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].intId);
      name = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].nameStud);
      email = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].emailStud);
      age = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].ageStud);
      hobby = clsHelp.parseToString(objectDat[i].hobbyStud);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById("BioTbl");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var idx = row.insertCell(0);
    var namex = row.insertCell(1);
    var emailx = row.insertCell(2);
    var agex = row.insertCell(3);
    var hobbyx = row.insertCell(4);

    action = `<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='popUpForm(${id}, "${name}", "${email}", "${age}", "${hobby}")'>Edit</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn - danger' onclick='deletedetailquestion(" ${id} ")'>Delete</button> `;

    var actionx = row.insertCell(5);

    idx.innerHTML = id;
    namex.innerHTML = name;
    emailx.innerHTML = email;
    agex.innerHTML = age;
    hobbyx.innerHTML = hobby;
    actionx.innerHTML = action;
    sortList();
  }

  $("#hiddenObject").val(JSON.stringify(objectDat));
}
```

and here's the popupForm code:

```
function popupForm(id, name, email, age, hobby) {
  $("#popUp #intId").val(id);
  $("#popUp #nameStud").val(name);
  $("#popUp #emailStud").val(email);
  $("#popUp #ageStud").val(age);
  $("#popUp #hobbyStud").val(hoby);
  $("#popUp").modal({ show: true, backdrop: false });
}
```

popUp form is in HTML

```
<div id="popUp" Class="modal fade">
  <form id="frmIndex_Ket">
    <div class="modal-header bg-green">
      <Button
        type="button"
        Class="close"
        data-dismiss="modal"
        aria-label="Close"
        id="btnCloseModalSelectedVendor"
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </Button>
      <h5 Class="modal-title">Add Question</h5>
    </div>
    <div Class="modal-body">
      <div style="overflow-x:auto">
        <div class="block">
          <div class="block-content np">
            <div class="box-header with-border text-right">
              <a id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="row-form">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="lblid" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                  Id
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intId" readonly />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="lblSN" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                  Name
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    maxlength="2"
                    id="name"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="lblSF" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                  Email
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="lblSD" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                  Age
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="lblSD" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                  hobby
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hobby" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want to save the data each table row whenever I make new/edit the row using "popUp" to local storage (when I click the 'btnSave' button) and show the data from local storage to UI (in the dynamic table). So when I save the header it will store all of the rows to the database.

So basically I want to store temporary data in local storage. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+store+row+localStorage+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also please read up on [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)